# Bootstrap dropdown mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

How to make Bootstrap dropdown in `.navbar` mobile version looks like that which is in desktop version? I need this because I don't use `.navbar` collapse and when the dropdown is open it looks like that: [Dropdown mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pEc4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague and you should really have some code. However, I'd stick to the standard bootstrap navbar and I assume that's what you want. Here's an example from the bootstrap site (right click and view source on your browser):

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/